# XML Schema - Unique attribute value + parent attribute value

Tags: xml, schema, unique

Wanting to write a schema that tests to see if the combination of an attribute + the parent node attribute is unique.

Have the following so far

```
<xs:unique name="specify_req_once_in_traceability_section">
    <xs:selector xpath="./artefact/doc/relationship"/>
<xs:field xpath="@parent_sec"/>
</xs:unique>
```

but if I try to include the parent_doc using .. I get unexpected token --- I am guessing the parent axis is not allowed

xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <artefact>
             <doc parent_doc="fred">
                   <relationship parent_sec="125"/>          
             </doc>
             <doc parent_doc="geoff">
                   <relationship parent_sec="119"/>
                   <relationship parent_sec="118"/>
                   <relationship parent_sec="117"/> 
                   <relationship parent_sec="118"/> 
             </doc>
             <doc parent_doc="fred">
                   <relationship parent_sec="125"/>
             </doc>
             <doc parent_doc="james">
                   <relationship parent_sec="125"/>
              </doc>
          </artefact>
    </root>
```

Comment: so the xml should fail as fred + 125 is duplicated;geoff + 118 is duplicated ; but james + 125 is unique

Comment: yes, parent axis is not allowed (http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#coss-identity-constraint), but the child axis is permitted. Have you tried selecting `<doc>` and using `@parent_sec`and `relationship/@parent_sec`as fields?

Comment: sorry should have said this before already done this .... The field XPath expression '@parent_doc' evaluated to more than one node for identity-constraint 'specify_req_once_in_traceability_section'...... failing on the geoff node as does not know what relationship node to choses

Answer (score 0):

I tested my hypothesis in the comment and it works using the xerces version in JDK 6. I simplified the schema a bit, but the general structure is the same:

**Schema**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="doc" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="relationship" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:attribute name="ps" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="pd" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="u1">
        <xs:selector xpath="doc"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@pd"/>
        <xs:field xpath="relationship/@ps" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Instance document**

```
<root>
<doc pd="fred">
    <relationship ps="125" />
</doc>
<doc pd="geoff">
    <relationship ps="119" />
    <relationship ps="118" />
    <relationship ps="117" />
    <relationship ps="118" />
</doc>
<doc pd="fred">
    <relationship ps="125" />
</doc>
<doc pd="james">
    <relationship ps="125" />
</doc>
</root>
```

When validated, xerces give error message:

[Error] :13:28: Duplicate unique value [fred,125] declared for identity constraint of element "root".

If you change the second james' relationship ps to 126, the document validates without errors.

Comment: which version of xsd are you using .... just tried this using Kernow --- using Xerces - XML Schema 1.1  ---- got this error ---- file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/u522812/Desktop/tesr.xml failed:
cvc-identity-constraint.3: Field "./relationship/@parent_sec" of identity constraint "u1" matches more than one value within the scope of its selector; fields must match unique values.

Comment: ahhh ... if you are using XML Schema 1.0 (one-point-zero) it is not doing it correctly - there is a duplication within the pd=geoff node and it is not raising it as a validation error

Comment: Turns out that JDK 6 internal xerces version is 2.6.2. If I switch to 2.9.1 or 2.11.0 I get same the errors as you (but still XML schema 1.0).

Comment: but do you agree it should be raising an error? --- ie. geoff/118 is a duplicate.

Comment: Well, you know, that's beyond my competence. However, I was triggered by this mail conversation http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2005Nov/0031.html. In short, when the spec is open for interpretations, results will vary (Shame that I didn't see the duplicate "geoff, 118", though. Of course it's a duplicate!)